# Android round corner buttons with layout_weight="1" is not displying round corners

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin

I have two horizontal buttons with layout_weight="1". I have added button style for round corner. but round corner style is not visible with layout_weight="1". If I remove layout_weight="1", buttons shows round corner and buttons size get mismatch. but I want both. Same button style is showing rounded buttons on same page but that button doesn't have any weight. Please let me know what I am missing.

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPas"
            android:text="Pas"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@layout/btn_round" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCar"
            android:text="Car"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@layout/btn_round" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Button style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <layer-list>
      <item android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp">
        <shape>
          <corners android:radius="10dp"></corners>
          <solid android:color="#2196F3"></solid>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```

[image: Check Image]

Comment: You are not using Android Studio, are you?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio and Xamarin android

Comment: Then why didn't you tag them?

Answer (score 0):

Hello don't worry your implementation needs some simple edits I have implemented it and it worked with weights so please try it :) , Create new Drawable resource file in drawable folder btn_round.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="10dp"></corners>
                    <solid android:color="#2196F3"></solid>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and in your layout put this:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:text="btn1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_round" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:text="btn2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_round" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have tried your solution but it is not working. I am applying this style from layout folder and it is working for other buttons

Comment: can u include screenshot , what is not working  and what is displaying

Comment: and how are u using big letters in layout folder ? you can't

Comment: Added image. I am using Xamarin android. It takes upper case characters in name

Comment: can u add a screenshot of what is happening,maybe i will be able to help you better

Comment: You can check in above image that button pas and car must be round. as I have applied same style to all buttons in that page